# Google analytics with !IsPostBack

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, ispostback

We're using google analytics in our webforms site. I have the google analytics javascript loading in the head section of the masterpage like this...

```
    <%if (!IsPostBack)
  {%>
<script src="Content/google.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<%} %>
```

my question is, will this affect the statistics on page visit duration? We are trying to analyse how long the users are on the page for.

before i did not use the !IsPostBack statement and we found that the page visits were increasing with every post back. so now we should get better data on actual page visits, but will this affect the visit duration stats?

Comment: The problem is that for asp.net it's the same page, but for the browser (and GA) it's a new request (to the same url). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127634/how-to-track-distinct-pageviews-on-asp-net-postbacks-in-google-analytics

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question.
Will google track the visit duration of that page when the google script is not loaded on a postback? (there can be many postbacks on some of our pages)